# Zebra printing code example for CPCL language (Other then TEST example)

Tags: android-bluetooth, zebra-printers

```
String cpclConfigLabel = "! 0 200 200 406 1\n" + "ON-FEED IGNORE\n" + "BOX 20 20 10 10 8\n" + "T 0 6 137 177 TEST\n" + "PRINT\n";
```

These lines comes with Zebra test demo code, I am not very good with CPCL languages and the corresponding commands , e.g

```
! U1 JOURNAL
! U1 SETLP 5 2 46
 AURORA’S FABRIC SHOP
! U1 SETLP 5 0 24
 123 Castle Drive, Kingston, RI 02881
 (401) 555-4CUT
! U1 SETLP 7 0 24
 4:20 PM Thursday, June 04, 2020 Store: 142
 Order Number: #59285691
 Status: ! U1 SETSP 10
INCOMPLETE ! U1 SETSP 0
Item Description Quant. Price Subtotal Tax
1211 45” Buckram 5 yds @ $3.42/yd $17.10 Y
Z121 60” Blue Silk 10 yds@ $15.00/yd $150.00 N
Z829 60” Muslin 20 yds@ $1.00/yd $20.00 Y
 SUBTOTAL: $187.10
 RHODE ISLAND SALES TAX 7.00%: $2.60
TOTAL: $189.70
! U1 SETLP 7 1 48
 PLEASE BRING THIS RECEIPT TO THE CASHIER
 WITH THE REST OF YOUR PURCHASES.
! U1 CENTER
! U1 B 128 1 2 100 0 0 59285691 ST 187.10 T 2.60 ,
```

How do i get bytes from this print command and so , So can anyone have some suggestions how to do print receipt commands using CPCL?

Appreciated your effort.

Answer (score 1):

I have a good document you can look into, it has so many examples,
please find the document here [1](https://www.zebra.com/content/dam/zebra/manuals/en-us/printer/cpcl-pm-en.pdf), and please find this example I used to print a receipt:

```
! 0 200 200 600 1
PCX 0 1 !<B.PCX
T 0 4 1 125  Paid: 5 $
T 5 0 125 160        Date: 12/12/2012
T 5 0 125 179        Time: 12:12
T 5 0 125 217        User: AAA
T 5 0 125 236        Details
T 5 0 125 255        Card Price: 2
T 5 0 125 274        Balance: 3
T 5 0 25 293             Thank you 
T 5 0 40 312                   www.aa.aa.aa
FORM
PRINT
```

this command `PCX 0 1 !<B.PCX` is to print a logo that is downloaded on the printer.
the rest are TEXT commands.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your time , will look into it .

Comment: As an additional information, if you want to use different fonts for printing, you need to download the fonts to the printer first and giving them names while downloading to the printer. For example, if your font name is SWF12.CPF, you can use this font like T SWF12.CPF 0 125 180    Receipt. Basically you give the font name after T.

Answer (score 1):

it's too late but i want to answer the question. Maybe someone needed this.

Here is documentation
[CPCL Programming Language Documentation](https://support.zebra.com/cpws/docs/comtec/PROMAN-CPCL_RevY.pdf)

check it out.

You prepare your receipt, Then you must comminucate to your printer.

This is Xamarin.Android example:

```
public override Task<int> Print(byte[] command)
    {
        return Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(DeviceName))
                return -1;

            using BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.DefaultAdapter;
            BluetoothDevice device = (from bd in bluetoothAdapter?.BondedDevices
                                      where bd?.Name == DeviceName
                                      select bd).FirstOrDefault();

            if (device == null)
                throw new Exceptions.PrinterException("Device Not Found!", new NullReferenceException());

            try
            {
                using BluetoothSocket bluetoothSocket = device.CreateRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(
                    //UUID.FromString(Guid.NewGuid().ToString())
                    UUID.FromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb")
                    );
                if (!bluetoothSocket.IsConnected)
                    await bluetoothSocket.ConnectAsync();

                bluetoothSocket.OutputStream.Flush();
                await bluetoothSocket.OutputStream.WriteAsync(command, 0, command.Length);
                bluetoothSocket.OutputStream.Flush();
                bluetoothSocket.Close();
                return 1;
            }
            catch (Exception exp)
            {
                throw new Exceptions.PrinterException("An error occurred.", exp);
            }
        });
    }
```

Using:

```
string receipt = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(YourReceiptAsString);
await Print(receipt);
```

I hope this is going to help someone.
Take care!